# How I call a function with multi accounts?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I created a smart contract that should execute a function after its called by two owners, if and only if both owners call for function X, then this function is performed. It's like a multi signature type. My code is below, but its still not operational. The contract should send 1 Ether to the Wallet account after its called by the two Owners. Please, any one could help me. Thanks in advance.

```
 `pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

  contract MyContract {

  address Owner1;
  address Owner2;
  address Wallet;
  mapping(address => bool) signed;
  mapping(address => uint) balances;

  constructor() public payable {
   Owner1 = 0xC20201d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2777E8fa733c;
   Owner2 = 0x54201A09ACff6D2A60DcdF8896AFf308FDDC160C;
   Wallet = 0x30E09Fa68430Def6978ED1a3E8f5ed473A04024c;
   }

   function Sign() public {
   require (msg.sender == Owner1 || msg.sender == Owner2);
   require (signed[msg.sender] == false);
   signed[msg.sender] = true;
    }

   function Reward() public payable returns (string) {
   require (signed[Owner1] == true && signed[Owner2] == true);
   Wallet.transfer(1 ether); 
   signed[Owner1] = false; 
   signed[Oener2] = false; 
   }
     }
```

`

Comment: Your logic is not correct. If i have understood right you would like to send 1 ether to your Wallet account. That means you have to define from which account this 1 ether should be deducted? either owner1 1 or owner2? for example 1st the owner1 came and signed the transaction then the owner2 came and signed it and as the second transaction is being signed by the owner2 then this 1 ether should be deducted  from the owner2 account and you should transfer 1 ether to the Wallet account with owner2 account. I hope it helps

Comment: Hi Hsn, the 1 ether will be deduced from the contract balance. So, the contract has a balance of Ethers that will be send to the Wallet address after the function Reward is called by if and only by the two owners. If only one owner call this function, the function should be not executed.

Comment: give the answer i posted a try. worked fine for me..

Comment: Its works for you that the two owners call the function then its executed?

Comment: Yes, exactly....

Comment: Quik question: the deposit used only to aliment the contract balance with Ether, right?

Comment: take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397786/how-to-deposit-ether-to-an-account-using-solidity-and-web3 .. mapping is needed for it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code below first you need to deposit some ether from your account to deposit function. and then you can call the sign and reward function

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

  contract MyContract {

  address Owner1;
  address Owner2;
  address Wallet;
  mapping(address => bool) signed;
  mapping(address => uint) balances;

  constructor() public payable {
   Owner1 = 0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB;
   Owner2 = 0x583031D1113aD414F02576BD6afaBfb302140225;
   Wallet = 0xdD870fA1b7C4700F2BD7f44238821C26f7392148;
   }
   
   function deposit() payable returns(bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] +=msg.value;
        return true;
    }

   function Sign() public {
   require (msg.sender == Owner1 || msg.sender == Owner2);
   require (signed[msg.sender] == false);
   signed[msg.sender] = true;
    }

   function Reward() public payable returns (string) {
   require (signed[Owner1] == true && signed[Owner2] == true);
   Wallet.transfer(1 ether); 
   signed[Owner1] = false; 
   signed[Owner2] = false; 
   }
     }
```